# How to select MAX date from a list of records in Excel - project dashboard

Tags: excel, vlookup, project-management

I want to show the project start and end date (total duration) and I have data that breaks down each project into its respective milestone. Each milestone has its own start and end date.

How can I do a lookup based on "project name" and search for the min and max date to show on my main dashboard?

I tried max(vlookup()) but it wouldn't work.

Would appreciate some guidance on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would use `=MAXIFS` & `=MINIFS` to achieve this, similar to a `SUMIFS` function in terms of the input logic.

`=maxifs( [Max Range], [Project Name Range], [Project Name] )`

`=minifs( [Min Range], [Project Name Range], [Project Name] )`

These functions seem to only exist in Office 365.

Comment: Hi, my excel do not support maxif/minif functions..

Comment: tried using aggregate formula and it worked for me!https://superuser.com/questions/1312647/alternative-function-of-maxifs-minifs-in-excel